# Hahn-Banach Extensions

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Let $H=\{x\in X:\phi(x)=\|\phi\|\}$ and $M$ be subspaces of $X$ such that $H\subset M$ and $U(M)=\{x\in X:\|x\|=1\}$ be a unit ball in $M$ and let $\phi\in M^*$. Suppose that there exists a functional $\psi \in X^*$ and a positive number $\gamma$  such that $\psi(x)<\gamma<\psi(y)$ for all $x\in U(M)$ and $y\in H$. Now, is it possible to use the Hahn Banach extension theorem and extend $\phi$?

Comment: As stated, your question makes little sense. Your $\phi$ is defined on $M$, so $H$ is not well-defined, unless you only consider $x\in M$: but in that case the inclusion $H\subset M$ is trivial. More importantly, Hahn-Banach always applies, so without any hypothesis whatsoever, if you have $\phi\in M^*$ then you can extend it to $\tilde\phi\in X^*$ with $\|\tilde\phi\|=\|\phi\|$.

Comment: But for $\phi$ to be extended, it has to be dominated by a sub-linear functional according to the Hahn-Banach Theorem, right? Does the functional $\psi$ dominate $\phi$?

Comment: You are right if you are looking at the most plain, first version of Hahn-Banach. What you do then is to take the sublinear functional to be $q(x)=\|\varphi\|\,\|x\|$. You still don't need those other hypotheses.

Comment: Thank you. One more question: If we choose any $\overline{x}\in X$ such that 
 $\phi(\overline{x})=\|\phi\|$ and any z∈X such that ϕ(z)=0 which implies $\psi(\overline{x}+\lambda z)>\gamma$ for a positive number $\lambda$ with all the hypotheses in my question above, how do I prove that ψ(z)=0?